# How does the "is" operator work with dynamic objects?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic, dynamic-language-runtime

How does the `is` operator work with respect to the DLR?

To make my question a little more explicit, consider the following signature:

```
 public bool Is<T>(Func<dynamic> getInstance)
 { 
     return getInstance() is T;
 }
```

By default, what conditions are necessary for `Is<T>` to return `true`?  Furthermore, does the DLR provide any mechanism to customize this behavior?

Comment: What type of customization behavior would you want?

Comment: @ReedCopsey, granular ducktyping: I would like to be able to do something like have an interface: `public interface INamed { string Name { get; } }` and when I check `getInstance() is INamed` to have my custom `DynamicMetaObject` implementation return true iff the dynamic object contains a string property named "Name".  Any suggestions?

Comment: You'd need to implement the checks yourself, probably by using reflection against the interface, etc.

Comment: `a is B` <=> `typeof(B).IsAssignableFrom(a.GetType())`

Comment: @ReedCopsey, I get that.  But is there any way to map the `is` syntax to those checks?

Comment: @dialer, except for when `a == null`

Comment: @smartcaveman structural typing with DynamicMetaObject, is pretty much impossible as it doesn't have an api for testing for implementation. I wrote a full [library that provides easy access](https://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) to pretty much all c# dlr apis.

Comment: @jbtule, maybe...  I'm thinking that I could get what I want by generating dynamic proxies that implement all these interfaces and inherit from the assigned `T` type.  Do you see a problem here?

Comment: @smartcaveman Well that's where framework started, `IMyInterface myInterface = Impromptu.ActLike(expando)`. Dynamic Implementation static interface.

Comment: @jbtule, I've actually read over the source of `impromptu` before, but haven't used it.  Does it support what I'm describing out of the box?

Comment: @smartcaveman It won't test for an interface on an IDynamicMetaObjectProvider, but you can wrap a static interface around any IDynamicMetaObjectProvider and that interface can be tested for.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27124/discussion-between-jbtule-and-smartcaveman)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At runtime, `dynamic` is treated the same as `object`, which means that the runtime type of the `getInstance` delegate's result will be used to perform this check.  The only difference using `dynamic` here will cause is that there will be no compile time checking, and dynamic binding will be used at runtime to perform this check on the dynamic object returned by `getInstance`.

> By default, what conditions are necessary for Is to return true?

The delegate passed in will need to return a type which, at runtime, is compatible with `T`.

> Furthermore, does the DLR provide any mechanism to customize this behavior?

No.  This is going to use the standard rules for C# types.  Any custom behavior would need to be written into the logic itself.

Comment: So, the result is the same as  `typeof(T).GetType().IsInstanceOfType(getInstance())`?

Comment: @smartcaveman It's more like using [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx), ie: `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(getInstance().GetType())`

Comment: There aren't actually any differences in this case to using `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `is` already is a runtime test, there is no extra runtime binding being done, in fact there won't be any compiled IL difference to

```
 public bool Is<T>(Func<object> getInstance)
 { 
     return getInstance() is T;
 }
```

The IL for the method body of both `Is<T>(Func<object> getInstance)` and `Is<T>(Func<dynamic> getInstance)`:

```
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] bool CS$1$0000)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldarg.1 
    L_0002: callvirt instance !0 [mscorlib]System.Func`1<object>::Invoke()
    L_0007: isinst !!T
    L_000c: ldnull 
    L_000d: cgt.un 
    L_000f: stloc.0 
    L_0010: br.s L_0012
    L_0012: ldloc.0 
    L_0013: ret
```

So the answer is that `is` keyword is not effected by the usage of the DLR, it works the same as if you use the type `object`.

Comment: So there is no compiled difference at all? What if it was an instance of DynamicObject or something like that?

Comment: If it's a DynamicObject it will only be true if bool Is<DynamicObject>. And yes you can write the code, compile it and both ways will be the same IL in this case.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. DynamicObject is treated specially. It can be used to customize lots of behavior (think of ExpandoObject). It also has a TryConvert function. Also, what if the object is a python object? I'm sure python rules for type conversion are different so they are probably customizable?!

Comment: @usr `is` doesn't trigger type conversion in c#. If the runtime could change `is` behavior any more then the compiler would generate dynamic binding code, but it doesn't. I've added the IL to the answer.